# MySQL: select no more than X rows of one type

Tags: mysql

With the following table

```
some_table
+----+-------------+------+
| id | some_column | type |
+----+-------------+------+
|  1 |       value |    1 |
|  2 |       value |    2 |
|  3 |       value |    1 |
| .. |         ... |  ... |
| .. |         ... |  ... |
+----+-------------+------+
```

I need to make a select that would deliver all rows with type 1 but the maximum of 2 of type 2. Is it possible with one statement?

Comment: You can `UNION` two queries together.

Comment: @MattClark - was this comment intended for a different question?

Comment: I misread the question, though OP was looking for only one of each _type_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

```
select id, some_column, type from some_table where type = 1
UNION
(select id, some_column, type from some_table where type = 2 limit 2)
```

you might want to specify some `ORDER BY` clause in second query, otherwise it is not guaranteed which 2 rows from `type = 2` you will get